# iPhone Connectivity for Ford SYNC Applink™ Emulator

Tags: ios, iphone, synchronization

I have setup the virtual box and installed Ubuntu and also installed “SYNC Applink™ Emulator” with help of your document (ref link: https://developer.ford.com/pages/tools-ios) in both my Windows and Mac.

I have also configured the Port forwarding setup on virtualBox manager and also I connected both system and iPhone in the same network , but still my iPhone not displayed on Phone tab of Sync emulator.
I have checked with your sample application of HelloSDL and App Store application of Spotify , this 2 application also not showing in Apps tab in Emulator.

please help us solve the problems.

Comment: i am facing the same problem. iOS phone is not connecting to simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try the following steps in HSDLProxyManager.m class:

1. In the method startProxy, uncomment the method which connects via TCP/IP and then comment the method which uses USB.
2. Change the variable RemoteIpAddress according to the ip of your virtual machine.